# Why is my app crashing during Table View Insert Row?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsstring, uitextview

My app is only crashing in a specific way.  Here's a break down of what's going on.

I can type in text in a UITextView and tap a button that saves the text and adds a row to a UITableView in another UIViewController.  I can then tap on the desired cell from the UITableView and that UIViewController will dismiss and the text will appear again on the main UIViewController.

I have another button that simply clears out the UITextView so I can type in new text.

If I view the text from an added row and then tap the "Add" button to input new text and then tap the "Save" button my app crashes.

Here's some of the code:

didSelectRow Code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
     //Setting the text stored in an array into a NSString here
    _displayString = [_savedNoteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

save button code:

```
- (IBAction)saveNote
{
    if (_noteView.aTextView.text == nil)
    {
        [_noteArray addObject:@""];

        Note * tempNote = [[Note alloc] init];
        _note = tempNote;

        [_savedNotesViewController.savedNoteArray addObject:tempNote];
        NSIndexPath * tempNotePath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: [_savedNotesViewController.savedNoteArray count]-1 inSection:0];
        NSArray * tempNotePaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:tempNotePath];
    [_savedNotesViewController.noteTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tempNotePaths withRowAnimation:NO];

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AddNote" object:nil];

    }
    else
    {
        [_noteArray addObject:self.noteView.aTextView.text];

        Note * tempNote = [[Note alloc] init];
       _note = tempNote;

        [_savedNotesViewController.savedNoteArray addObject:tempNote];
        NSIndexPath * tempNotePath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[_savedNotesViewController.savedNoteArray count]-1 inSection:0];
        NSArray * tempNotePaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:tempNotePath];

        //**** This is where the app is crashing *****
        [_savedNotesViewController.noteTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tempNotePaths withRowAnimation:NO];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AddNote" object:nil];

    }

    Note * myNote = [Note sharedNote];
    myNote.noteOutputArray = _noteArray;

}
```

add butt code (makes a new UITextView):

```
- (IBAction)addButtonTapped
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AddNote" object:nil];
}
```

in my viewWillAppear to show the selected row text I do this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.noteView.aTextView.text = _savedNotesViewController.displayString;
}
```

note code (singleton class):

```
 static Note * sharedNote = nil;

 - (id)initWithNote:(NSString *)newNote
 {
    self = [super init];

    if (nil != self)
    {
        self.note = newNote;
    }

    return self;
}

+ (Note *) sharedNote
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedNote == nil)
        {
            sharedNote = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return sharedNote;
}
```

When the app crashes I get this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Note isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8875f20'
```

Stepping through my code, the text is being added to the array, but when it comes time to insertRowsAtIndexPaths the app blows up.

Any advice is much appreciated!

*** EDIT // TableView Code ****

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_savedNoteArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    //I have a feeling this could be where an issue is. 
    NSString * cellString = [_savedNoteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellString;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Where is `[Note isEqualToString:]` code? Unrecognised selector sent means you are calling method that is not declared/defined for that object. Please add the code for table view controller and also for the line for which application is crashing as mentioned in reason.

Comment: are you returning proper value in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_noteArray count];
}`
You have not added table view controllers code. Please add it. could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

One potential issue (which may not be your crash, but will cause issues regardless) is that you are storing Note objects in the `savedNoteArray` BUT you are trying to use them as strings (your code below):

```
//Setting the text stored in an array into a NSString here
_displayString = [_savedNoteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Then you assign that displayString to a UITextView's text property (which is supposed to be an NSString*):

`self.noteView.aTextView.text = _savedNotesViewController.displayString;`

The short form of this issue can be summarized as...

```
Note *note = [[NSNote alloc] init];
[array addObject:note];
textView.text = array[0];
```

This will clearly cause issues. You're basically assigning a 'Note' object to something that is supposed to be a string.

This probably leads into the crash that you're experiencing in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of your table view data source. Are you using Note objects there as well, or are you properly assigning NSStrings to views?

Comment: That probably _is_ causing the crash, the label is probably checking to see if the incoming text is the same as the current text to see if it needs redrawing.

Comment: I tried this first and it works up until the issue I have posted above:  
    NSString * cellString = [_savedNoteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellString;